# Android: how to listen dynamically added button's click?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have the following code that upon image capture, places a RelativeLayout container, which contains ImageView of the image and Button that is supposed to be the X (Remove) button.

```
private void addImage(Bitmap photo) {
  RelativeLayout rLayout = new RelativeLayout(getApplicationContext()); // Any difference between 'this' and 'getApplicationContext()'?

  RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParas(
          RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
          RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

  rLayout.setLayoutParams(params);

  ImageView imageView = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
  imageView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(100, 100));
  imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
  imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);

  RelativeLayout.LayoutParams bParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
          RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
          RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
  bParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_RIGHT, imageView.getId());
  bParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_TOP, imageView.getId());
  bParams.setMargins(0, -10, -10, 0);

  Button closeButton = new Button(getApplicationContext());
  closeButton.setText("X"); // This will be an icon later
  closeButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED); // For visualization purposes
  closeButton.setLayoutParams(bParams);

  rLayout.addView(imageView);
  rLayout.addView(closeButton);

  parentLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.horizontal_scrolling_linear_layout);
  parentLinearLayout.addView(rLayout);
}
```

The ideal scenario is having a close/delete button on top-right corner of the image, that upon click will remove the parent RelativeLayout from it's parent. Some styling and placements in the code might not make sense, I am JUST starting Android Development so any help will be appreciated. I am also including small questions in comments that would help me clear things up in Android Dev.

Question is: How can I capture button (X) click and remove the parent relative layout from the code?

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
closeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View view) {
        ((ViewGroup) rLayout.getParent()).removeView(rLayout);
    }
});
```

Comment: can't try this now because the program is failing to capture the image. Debugging now. I'll keep you posted.

Comment: worked perfectly, and is the shortest answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
// Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem...

private void addImage(Bitmap photo) {
        RelativeLayout rLayout = new RelativeLayout(getApplicationContext());

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        rLayout.setLayoutParams(params);

        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(100, 100));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams bParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        bParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_RIGHT, imageView.getId());
        bParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_TOP, imageView.getId());
        bParams.setMargins(0, -10, -10, 0);

        Button closeButton = new Button(getApplicationContext());
        closeButton.setText("X"); // This will be an icon later
        closeButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED); // For visualization purposes
        closeButton.setLayoutParams(bParams);

        closeButton.setTag(0,parentLinearLayout);
        closeButton.setTag(1,rLayout);
        closeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                LinearLayout parentLinearLayout = (LinearLayout)view.getTag(0);
                RelativeLayout rLayout = (RelativeLayout)view.getTag(1);
                parentLinearLayout.removeView(rLayout);
            }
        });
        rLayout.addView(imageView);
        rLayout.addView(closeButton);

        parentLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.horizontal_scrolling_linear_layout);
        parentLinearLayout.addView(rLayout);
}
```

Comment: But won't this remove all the views of the `LinearLayout` while the OP wants to remove only **one** particular view

Comment: but he added only one layout in it

Comment: This code will dynamically keep adding `RelativeLayout`s to it's parent LinearLayout. @hiphopdroid is right, I want to remove THAT button's parent RelativeLayout.

Comment: @Grigor,have you add any other layout in parent LinearLayout ?

Comment: @Grigor, did you try my solution?

Comment: @Haresh, try to understand that @Grigor's code will dynamically add `RelativeLayout`s to the parent `LinearLayout`. So the code should be able to remove only that `RelativeLayout` which has the button which is clicked

Comment: @Haresh, hiphopdroid's answer is sweet and short and works perfectly. I am trying to avoid writing extra code as much as possible. Thanks for your effort though.

Answer (score 1):

I'd start by moving the following line into your Activity's onCreate():

```
parentLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.horizontal_scrolling_linear_layout);
```

This helps to reduce unnecessary reassignment as well as clutter. Once that's done, the following should suit your needs.

```
Button closeButton = new Button(getApplicationContext());
closeButton.setText("X"); // This will be an icon later
closeButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED); // For visualization purposes
closeButton.setLayoutParams(bParams);
closeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (parentLinearLayout != null) {
            parentLinearLayout.removeView(rLayout);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use

```
 closeButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
                 //override method  
                  public void onClick(View v) { 
                   //do something
                 }    
                 });
```

In addition,you can't remove the parent `RelativeLayout` ,because any view must be included by `viewGroup`.

And the difference between "this" and "getApplicationContext()" as you mentioned at the beginning is:

`this == yourActivity.this` ,it is activity's instance. However,`getApplicationContext()`  will get Application's instance.

Comment: Upvoted for explanation of `this` vs `getApplicationContext()`. Other than that, the code is missing the part that removes a RelativeLayout.